# Asp.Net How to get Summery of every Department

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

[image]

Hi guys, I hope some one will help me with this kind of problem. 
As you see in attached image, I have four tables one for Departments one for Categories one for Products and last one InventoryTable

```
Departments { DeptId, DeptName }

Category {CatId, CategoryName}
Product {PrId, PrName, CatId}
And Inventory {InventoryId, ProductId, DepartmentId, Status}
```

And I want to create a table that shows as attached image shows. I want to show status of every product in every department and total of that product.

By the way department do not need to poplate dynamicaly. I can write them manually.

This is my Model

```
public class SummeryOfInventoryModel
{
        public Product product { get; set; }
        public string productName { get; set; } 
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public Department department { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; } 
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

        public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

And this is How I'am trying to do Action Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetProductSummery()
{
     using (context)                                 
     {
        return (PartialView("_ProductSummery", await context.Inventory
               .Include(p =>p.Product).Include(d =>d.Department)
               .GroupBy(m => m.Product.PrName)
               .Select(g => new SummeryOfInventoryModel { productName = g.Key, Status = g.Sum(c => c.Status) })
               .ToListAsync()));
     }

}
```

But this givs me only Productname and total statuse of that product like this

```
Product  Totaly 
Audio       25
Ford        10
```

But what Iwant is

```
Product Ny  Paris   Berlin  Total
Audio   20  5                25
Ford    10                   10
Volvo       15         10    25
```

And this is my PartielView: Please Help, I would appreciate your help, Thank you

```
@model IEnumerable<Lager03.Models.SummeryOfInventoryModel>


<p>

</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th>
            Produkt

        </th>
        <th>
           Ny

        </th>
        <th>
            Paris
        </th>
        <th>
           Berlin
        </th>
        <th>
            Totalt 

        </th>


    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
 </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
        </td>


    </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: You code and you data naming does match. This making the things difficult to understood what actually have to do.

Comment: Sounds like you want to add amount for each `City` object (or somewhat else which contains every item from certain table) but your code seem doesn't include it yet. You need to provide model which matches the output definition.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto thank you for your response, Yes amount of status for each City. That's  model coming in and I realy do not know how to formulate it. Would appricate if you can help me.

Comment: @TanvirArjel thank you for your response. I realy want as you see in image. Cities does not to be dynamicaly. Would appricate if you could help me. Believe me I tried in hours but could not solve this problem. Thank you in advance!